# currency position magento

Tags: currency

i have tried change the currency position of my website cangurumoda.com.br/lojacangu/

it looks like: 200,00 R$

the corrency symbol should looks before the price, like this: R$ 200,00

well, have followed some tutorials, like:

http://php.quicoto.com/how-to-change-currency-position-in-magento/
http://www.everyuseful.com/programming/106-how-to-change-currency-symbol-position-in-magento

pls, need some help with that issue.

thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by 'change the position' and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which language do you have set up on your store? It should be that file. The symbol below represents your currency symbol, change it's location.

```
¤
```

Then open your FTP tool or SSH and delete all contents in the var/cache/ folder. Then it should work. If you have English set up on your store, edit the en.xml file. (I tried this on a demo store I use, and doing this works)

Follow every single step here: http://www.everyuseful.com/programming/106-how-to-change-currency-symbol-position-in-magento and you will succeed:

> 1. [In your Magento root, navigate to] /lib/Zend/Locale/Data
> 2. Download your language file (us.xml) for example
> 3. Open the xml file in any text or xml editor
> 4. search for `<currencyFormat>`
> 5. In the following line there is [a `<pattern>` element], change it from:
>
>    ```
>    <pattern>¤#,##0.00;(¤#,##0.00)</pattern>
>    ```
>
>    to
>
>    ```
>    <pattern>#,##0.00 ¤;(#,##0.00 ¤)</pattern>
>    ```
>
>    [i.e. move the currency symbol]
> 6. Save the local file, and upload it again to server, overwriting the
>      old one.

Comment: tnks! it's working now!!!

Answer (score 0):

go to ( lib/Zend/Currency.php ) move to line 196

```
if ($options['position'] !== self::STANDARD) {
        $value = str_replace('¤', '', $value);
        $space = '';
        if (iconv_strpos($value, ' ') !== false) {
            $value = str_replace(' ', '', $value);
            $space = ' ';
        }

        if ($options['position'] == self::LEFT) {
            $value = '¤' . $space . $value;//here the currency before the value (price)
        } else {
            $value = $value . $space . '¤';
        }
    }
```

TO MAKE THE CURRENCY AFTER THE VALUE (PRICE) :

```
if ($options['position'] !== self::STANDARD) {
        $value = str_replace('¤', '', $value);
        $space = ' ';//make space between the value and the currency
        if (iconv_strpos($value, ' ') !== false) {
            $value = str_replace(' ', '', $value);
            $space = ' ';
        }

        if ($options['position'] == self::LEFT) {
            $value = $value . $space . '¤' ;//print the currency after the value
        } else {
            $value = $value . $space . '¤';
        }
    }
```